# Not able to dynamically use id element for a GET request in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

I am trying to use handlebars.js to template a GET request from themoviedb. The idea is that the first get request and template show ALL the movies in the DB with pictures etc and when one of the titles is clicked, it prepends that particular movie with more information on that respective movie. To do this I am trying to use the data attr in the #clickable div with a data-id to which I have assigned the "{{ id }}" element. From there I have an .onclick event handler that saves the movie id to var Id. Lastly I concatenate the var Id to the second get request to populate the new template.

I keep getting an Uncaught Error You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined.

Here is the code -- please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>URDB!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">hello world</div>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script id="all" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="list">
    <div id="clickable" data-id={{ id }}><h4>{{ title }}</h4></div>
    <p>{{ release_date }}</p>
    <p>{{ vote_average }}</p>
    <h2><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w396{{poster_path}}"></h2>
  </div>
</script>
<script id="one" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="single">
    <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
    <p>{{ release_date }}</p>
    <p>{{ vote_average }}</p>
    <p>{{ imdb_id }}</p>
    <p>{{ tagline }}</p>
    <h2><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w396{{poster_path}}"></h2>
  </div>
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var source = $("#All").html();
  var source2 = $("#single").html();

  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var template2 = Handlebars.compile(source2);
  var myList = [];

    $.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=caa1990e26f7dab9052573323febcbdc', function(data){

    data.results.forEach(function(x){
      myList.push(x);
      var myNewHTML = template({
      title: x.title,
      release_date: x.release_date,
      vote_average: x.vote_average,
      poster_path: x.poster_path,
      id: x.id
      });

      $('body').append(myNewHTML);
      })
    });

   $("#clickable").on('click', function(){
    var Id = $(this).data('id');
   $.get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+Id+'?api_key=caa1990e26f7dab9052573323febcbdc', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var anotherHTML = template2({
        title: data.title,
        release_date: data.release_date,
        vote_average: data.vote_average,
        poster_path: data.poster_path,
        imdb_id: data.imdb_id,
        tagline: data.tagline
        });
        $('body').prepend(anotherHTML);
    })
   })
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

The id attributes you are referencing do not reflect your source code, which means you are passing `undefined` into `Handlebars.compile` and hence getting the error:

```
<script id="all" type="text/x-handlebars-template">...</script>
<script id="one" type="text/x-handlebars-template">...</script>

var source = $("#All").html();
var source2 = $("#single").html();
```

The issues are:

- `#All` - JavaScript is case-sensitive; the id in your script tag is all lowercase
- `#single` - The is no id `single` in your code; you should be looking for `one`!

### The solution ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLw8zj9f/1/))

- Change `#All` to `#all` or vice versa
- Change `#single` to `#one` or vice versa